# Halt closing the div; if hover over it

Tags: jquery

as shown below, if the user hover over the div then how to halt the fade out div? and if the is not hover the div then fadeout whatever the time is set to.?

below is the code i am using....for fadein and fadeout:

```
 $("#success").fadeOut('slow');
 $("#success").fadeIn('slow');
 $("#success").fadeTo(5000, 1).fadeOut(2000);
```

my div:

```
<div class="success"><a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>status message here...</div>
```

i tried this:

```
if ($('#success').is(':hover')) { //dont close me and reset the time ...}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: To sum up: mouseover = fadeIn && mouseout = fadeOut?

Comment: not exactly or maybe, so for an example, if i hover the div then i want the div to be stay as long as the user has focus/hover the div and once the user focus out/mouseout from the div then close the div (whatever the time is defined.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/krmNY/1/

JS

```
var $msg = $('#dvFadeMsg'); 
var timer = null; 

function StartFadeTimer(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $msg.fadeOut('slow');
    }, 1500); 
}

$('#dvFadeMsg').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer); 
}, function(){
    StartFadeTimer(); 
});

$msg.fadeIn('slow');
StartFadeTimer();
```

HTML

```
<div id="dvFadeMsg">Fade me if no mouse</div>​
```